# UIActivity View Controller with custom row (Like what's App did in edit photo)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I want to add `UIViewController` when tap on `UIImage`. I didn't find any custom `UIActivityViewController` all were simple sharing activity controller. custom Activity controller is shown in the image

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(
              activityItems: ["Check out this book! I like using Book Tracker.", ""],
              applicationActivities: nil
            )

            present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

*emphasized text*
this is the simple sharing UiActivity Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) for this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel"), style: .cancel)
{
    _ in
}
alert.addAction(cancel)

let take = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default)
{
    _ in

    // TODO Do something
}
alert.addAction(take)

let choose = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default)
{
    _ in

    // TODO Do something
}
alert.addAction(choose)

let deletePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .destructive)
{
    _ in

    // TODO Do something
}
alert.addAction(deletePhoto )

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: but space is missing between cancel and choose photo

Comment: Hello, please try again. You have to set the style of the cancel button to .cancel. I have edited the code.